# Connection to database fails in other computers

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, connection

I have made an Data Management program with VB.net. In my computer, it works correctly without any problems for connecting to [App Address]/database.mdf file. But when i test my program in other computers it can not connect to Database File. For Solving this problem i have installed *Microsoft SQL Server 2008* , *SQLExpress 2008* and *.Net Framework 4* for those computers.But i still have the same problem. Can anyone help me to fix this Please?

This is my Database Connection Code:

```
Me.School_Adapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\School.mdf" & ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
Me.School_Adapter.Fill(Me.School_DataSet.School_Table)
```

Comment: You need to show some code if you expect us to help you find the problem with the code. The only thing you can say from what you posted is: "Try changing your timeout to a larger number". But that wont help.

Comment: I have added my Connection String. Is that enough?